# Changing file extension using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a list of .eml files which are in a remote folder say

```
\\abcremote\pickup
```

I want to rename all the files from

```
xyz.eml to xyz.html
```

Could you guys help me do that using ruby.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Improving the previous answer a little:

```
require 'fileutils'
Dir.glob('/path_to_file_directory/*.eml').each do |f|
    FileUtils.mv f, "#{File.dirname(f)}/#{File.basename(f,'.*')}.html"
end
```

The `File.basename(f,'.*')` will give you the name without the extension otherwise the files will endup being file_name.eml.html instead of file_name.html

Comment: Never knew about the second arg to `File.basename`. So much cleaner than some nasty thing like `File.basename(f).sub(/\.[^.]+$/, '')` that I've always done before.

Answer (score 12):

Rake offers a simple command to change the extension:

```
require 'rake'
p 'xyz.eml'.ext('html') # -> xyz.html
```

Improving the previous answers again a  little:

```
require 'rake'
require 'fileutils'
Dir.glob('/path_to_file_directory/*.eml').each do |filename|
    FileUtils.mv( filename, filename.ext("html"))
end
```

Comment: That is great for rails app, since you use `rake` by default anyway

Answer (score 6):

[Pathname](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) has the [`sub_ext()`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-sub_ext) method to replace the extension, as well as [`glob()`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-c-glob) and [`rename()`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-rename), allowing the accepted answer to be rewritten a little more compactly:

```
require 'pathname'
Pathname.glob('/path_to_file_directory/*.eml').each do |p|
    p.rename p.sub_ext(".html")
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Simpler

```
'abc . . def.mp3'.sub /\.[^\.]+$/, '.opus'
```

Comment: should be `\.[^\.]+$` (escaping the first dot) :)

Answer (score 2):

as long as you have access to that folder location, you should be able to use `Dir.glob` and `FileUtils.mv`

```
Pathname.glob('path/to/directory/*.eml').each do |f|
  FileUtils.mv f, "#{f.dirname}/#{f.basename}.html"
end
```

Comment: I had to use `f.basename(f.extname)`, otherwise `basename` includes extension.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by using net-sftp library:
The below method will rename all the files with desired file extension which will also make sure other formats are untouched.

1. dir = "path/to/remote/directory"
2. actual_ext = ".eml"
3. desired_ext = ".html"

```html
require 'net/sftp'
  def add_file_extension(dir, actual_ext, desired_ext)
    Net::SFTP.start(@host, @username, @password) do |sftp|
      sftp.dir.foreach(dir) do |file|
        if file.name.include? actual_ext
          sftp.rename("#{dir}/#{file.name}", "#{dir}/#{file.name.slice! actual_ext}#{desired_ext}")
        else
          raise "I cannot rename files other than which are in #{actual_ext} format"
        end
      end
    end
  end
```